# How to split all triangles from a mesh?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, export

I have a model that uses indices to form the topology of the mesh. I'd like to split all triangles such that indices are not used, i.e. Each triangle has it's own 3 vertices. How can I do this in Blender? Note that the split modifier doesn't work, remember I need all indices to be gone.

Edit:
I've tried to use the split modifier with split angle at 0. That gives discontinuities when loaded as obj. I'm using an external [library](https://github.com/syoyo/tinyobjloader) for the loading. Here's an example of how this looks when loaded:

[image]

Comment: What is indices in this context? If vertex indices are meant then splitting geometry into separate faces won't work, each vertex will have an index regardless, there just will be more of them.

Comment: I only need the points so in this case I'm ignoring indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: Selecting everything in edit mode and pressing Crtl-E then selecting Edge Split will do what you want.

If I understand the question correctly you want each triangle to be separate from the rest of the mesh (so no vertex is used by more than one triangle).

One way to do this is to select everything in edit mode (vertex select is easiest although not necessary), press Alt-E and choose individual faces. Immediately right click to cancel the operation and then press Ctrl-I to select everything but the extruded faces. Once you delete the selected vertices you should be left with a mesh made of individual triangles.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I need :) I'd vote up but my rep is low on this stack.

Comment: I don't quite get how is this different from applying Edge Split modifer. Generally these operations do the same.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the object.
2. Go to the **Modifiers** Tab of the *Properties* Area.
3. Add an edge split modifier.
4. Set the **Split Angle** to **0°**. Apply the modifier.

[image: edge split modifier]

The all non planar edges have been split.

Comment: I've tried this. Please have a look at the edits to the question.